# dyld[85146]: Library not loaded: @rpath/some_pod.framework/some_pod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, dyld

I have an xcworkspace that has multiple targets in it and I've added a pod to one of the targets but when I run the app I get the following error.

`dyld[85146]: Library not loaded: @rpath/some_pod.framework/some_pod`

Structure looks like this

- MainApp

  - Main Target
  - Pods
  - Common
  - Networking

I import Common into my Main Target classes and use it that way. If I add the "some_pod" to my Main Target there is no problem but when I add it to Common then I get the error above.

I added the some_pod.framework to "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content" under Main Target and everything works fine but I'm a bit suspicious because it's the only framework that is under Pods/ directory.

What is the best way to handle this issue?

Thanks in advance